# How to find projection operator from a matrix without knowing basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a 6 by 6 matrix $A$. I have calculated its eigenvalues and eigen function. Now I need to take projection on a subspace (upper left 3 by 3 block matrix). How can I do that? Projection operator is defined as $\mathbb{P} = \sum_{i} |i><i|$. Let $M$ be the matrix whose each column correspond to eigen vector so I know how to find the projection matrix $\mathbb{p} = M(M^{T}M)^{-1}M^{T}$ but then how can I take the projection of subspace ?

Comment: The basis you are looking for should be the eigenfunctions. But you question is a little unclear. Maybe you could expand it a bit with an [edit].

Comment: I have edited my question I hope now it is clear.

Comment: Is there anything unclear?  I simply want to know that How can we take projection on the subspace of 6 by 6 matrix?

Comment: Let $|1>=(1,0,0,0,0,0)^T,...,|6>=(0,0,0,0,0,1)^T$,then a 6-by-6 matrix $A$ with elements $a_{ij}$ can be written as $A=\sum_{1\le i,j\le 6} a_{ij}|i><j|$. In my opinion, the projection onto a subspace (upper left 3 by 3 block matrix) is given by $\mathbb{P} = \sum_{1\le i,j\le 3} |i><j|$.

Comment: Can I say that in my question matrix  I need to consider only upper right part of matrix $M$. If that is the case what will be the summation range if I need to consider  bottom left block matrix or top right block matrix?

Comment: I think so for the upper right block matrix index i should be from 3 to 6 and j index will be from 1 to 3 .right?

Comment: 4 to 6 instead of 3 to 6.